# Problem with xml parsing in phonegap application

Tags: iphone, android, cordova

I want to parse xml webservice in my phonegap application  but i don't have any idea how is it  possiblem.I tried it with my local xml file which is stored in my remote server and  it is working fine but when i am calling server side xml file then i am not getting any result.Pls anybody have idea then please solve my issue. Pls any one have working simple code then pls send it to me. I tried to find out my solution from google but didn't get any answer .Please solve my issue.My server file is http://www.edumobile.org/blog/uploads/XML-parsing-data/Data.xml.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please try following code in your index.html file, I have tested the url (http://www.edumobile.org/blog/uploads/XML-parsing-data/Data.xml) in iPhone/Android Simulator and its work like charm.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="js/jquery-1.4.2.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
function bodyload(){
    alert("We are calling jquery's ajax function and on success callback xml parsing are done");
$.ajax({  
    url:'http://www.edumobile.org/blog/uploads/XML-parsing-data/Data.xml',  
    dataType:'application/xml', 
    timeout:10000,  
    type:'POST',  
    success:function(data) {
        $("#bookInFo").html("");
         $("#bookInFo").append("<hr>");
         $(data).find("Book").each(function () {
              $("#bookInFo").append("<br> Name: " + $(this).find("name").text());
              $("#bookInFo").append("<br> Address: " + $(this).find("address").text());
              $("#bookInFo").append("<br> Country: " + $(this).find("country").text());
              $("#bookInFo").append("<br><hr>");
         });
     },  
    error:function(XMLHttpRequest,textStatus, errorThrown) {     
      alert("Error status :"+textStatus);  
      alert("Error type :"+errorThrown);  
      alert("Error message :"+XMLHttpRequest.responseXML);
      $( "#bookInFo" ).append( XMLHttpRequest.responseXML);
    }
    });
}   
</script>
</head>
<body onload="bodyload()">
<button onclick="bodyload()">Ajax call</button>
<p id="bookInFo"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Output-
[image]

Comment: 1 important thing, please change jquery file's plugin name to One that present at your end.

Comment: Hello, those script file are unavailable. will you plz download jquery.js and then plug in into your html page.

Comment: am getting "NO TRANSPORT" error. http://www.jaysonragasa.net/files/test/resp.xml

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a2/jquery.mobile-1.0a2.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a2/jquery.mobile-1.0a2.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {

            $("#requestXML").click(function() {

                     $.ajax({
                      type: "POST",
                      url: "http://www.edumobile.org/blog/uploads/XML-parsing-data/Data.xml",
                      data: "{}",
                      cache: false,
                      dataType: "xml",
                      success: onSuccess
                    });

            });

            $("#resultLog").ajaxError(function(event, request, settings, exception) {
              $("#resultLog").html("Error Calling: " + settings.url + "<br />HTTP Code: " + request.status);
            });

            function onSuccess(data)
            {
            $("#resultLog").append(""+data);

                   $(data).find("Book").each(function () {
                        $("#resultLog").append("<br> Name: " + $(this).attr("name"));
                        $("#resultLog").append("<br> Address: " + $(this).attr("address"));
                        $("#resultLog").append("<br> Country: " + $(this).attr("country"));
                        $("#resultLog").append("<br><hr>");
                   });
               }
        });

    </script>
```

Button to call the above method:

```
<input id="requestXML" type="button" value="Request XML" />
```

Comment: Sir,not working pls see my error http://www.mediafire.com/?2ko925z4smk59u1 i am not getting any output pls help

Comment: I have updated above answer, add the js and css imports to your html. I prefer run it on emulator or device.